# Предложение с прямой речью

Tags: прямая-речь, пунктуация

Наткнулся у А.Солженицына на такую фразу: "Смолосидов хмуро сказал: "Нельзя! У меня насморк", и Рубин подчинился". В тексте знаки расставлены так, но возникает вопрос: "Почему перед словами "и Рубин" стоит только запятая, а не запятая и тире?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Согласно правилу:

> Если прямая речь находится внутри
> авторских слов, то перед ней ставится
> двоеточие, а после нее – запятая, тире
> или запятая и тире (по условиям
> контекста):

См. § 50,  Прямая речь внутри авторских слов [link text](http://fictionbook.ru/author/ditmar_yelyashevich_rozental/spravochnik_po_russkomu_yaziyku_punktuaciya/read_online.html?page=17)

Из примеров по ссылке:

> Приехав на дачу в большой компании…
> брат вдруг говорил: «Мишка, пойдём на
> биллиард», и они, запершись, играли по
> три часа на биллиарде (Сим.) – запятая
> перед союзом и в сложносочиненном
> предложении

Comment: Марина, спасибо за интересный ответ. Подожду другие варианты и, если не окажется интереснее, приму Ваш.

Answer (score 0):

> Наткнулся у А.Солженицына на такую фразу

Соженицин вообще часто отступал от действующей орфографии (и пунктуации) по разным причинам. 
Но здесь все правильно. Тире ставится, когда вторая часть фразы продолжает первую. Здесь же фраза разбивается на две, представляя собой сложносочиненное предложение.

§ 136. Если прямая речь оказывается внутри слов автора, то она заключается в кавычки, а перед ней ставится двоеточие; прямая речь начинается с прописной буквы. После прямой речи знаки препинания расставляются следующим образом:
...
а) запятая ставится, если она была необходима в месте разрыва вводящих слов автора: Сказав: «До скорой встречи», она быстро вышла из комнаты;
...
б) тире ставится в случае отсутствия знака препинания на месте разрыва вводящих слов автора: Перебарывая неловкость, он пробормотал студенческую остроту: «У меня бабушка корью заболела» — и хотел придать начатому разговору непринужденную легковесность (Бонд.);
...
http://orthographia.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=137

ЗЫ Лопатин, конечно, но по сути все правильно, хотя формулировка оставляет желать. Но что-то похожее есть и у Розенталя, просто не в состоянии сейчас искать.

Comment: Зачем искать Розенталя, если я выше дала ссылку на него, на конкретный параграф.

Comment: Зачем ходить по вашим ссылкам, если вы не написали, на кого вы ссылаетесь и что именно там относится к делу?

Тем более, что я не это место имел в виду.

PS Источник, кстати, отвратительный. Для ссылок на Розенталя можно и поприличнее сайт найти. Без рекламы, налезающей на текст.

Comment: Солженицын отступал от правил в основном потому, что был человеком с техническим образованием, а не филологом, поэтому вполне возможно, что он попросту не знал некоторых правил.

Comment: Это очень хороший источник! Попробуйте найти в Интернете другой сайт с текстом именно этого пособия. Оно, кстати, более полное (за счет примеров), чем другие справочники по пунктуации. Есть еще у Розенталя замечательный "Справочник по пунктуации для работников печати" - но это вообще трудно находимая книга. 

Вот каждый раз заставите вспомнить "уверенность дилетанта — предмет зависти профессионала".

Comment: Это плохой источник. Попробуйте найти в интернете сайт с нормальным оформлением.

http://lib.rus.ec/b/118184/read

Comment: Источник
4.
Письменный памятник, документ, используемый при научном исследовании. Опираться на источники. Использовать все доступные источники. Доскональное знание источников. И. истории. Древнейший и.
http://www.gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?lop=x&bts=x&zar=x&ag=x&ab=x&sin=x&lv=x&az=x&pe=x&word=%E8%F1%F2%EE%F7%ED%E8%EA
Определитесь со значением слова для начала.

Comment: Для начала вы просили меня найти сайт, я нашел. **Ваши дальнейшие просьбы адресую модератору.**

Comment: Любите вы отредактировать свой ответ, после уже полученного комментария. Некрасиво. Что другой сайт нашли - хорошо. Я проверила, книга та же, можно пользоваться.

Comment: Мальчики и девочки! Я не хочу, чтобы из-за моего вопроса вы опять переругались. Кончайте! Я вас помирю. Не думаю, что Солженицын, как математик, занимался пунктуацией. Скорее всего, так расставил знаки редактор книги.

Comment: >Любите вы отредактировать свой ответ... Некрасиво. 

Я помешал вам устроить провокацию? Ну извините.

> проверила, книга та же, можно пользоваться
Надо ж, какое огорчение.  

>Я не хочу, чтобы из-за моего вопроса вы опять переругались  

Вы напрасно думаете, что дело в чьем-то вопросе. Мирить не надо, не получится. Согласен перенести обсуждение на другую площадку. 

>Не думаю, что Солженицын, как математик, занимался пунктуацией.  

Он это делал. Над ним еще Войнович нещадно издевался, в т. ч. и за это. А почему такое пренебрежение к математикам? Вы их считаете поголовно безграмотными?

Comment: Люди! У меня вся почта забита ссылками на ваши комментарии. Опять поругались? Делайте это в личке, нам это читать неприятно!  

Кстати, Marina-ja явно пытается сгладить конфликт, в отличие от ...

Comment: Математиков я уважаю. У меня жена математик и младший сын.